# Blazor Form with Dynamic Number of Questions

Tags: html, forms, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a testing application that pulls question/data answer from a database. The tests each have a different number of questions (some 10, some 15, some 12) that all need to be displayed with their answer choices (some multiple choice with 4 or 5 answers, some true/false). I want to utilize the Blazor form structure to allow access to input validation, but it seems that the form Model has to have a static number of members (i.e. only 10 test questions). I tried binding the form to a class with a List of length *n*, where *n* is the number of test questions (and consequently, the number of answers), but that only recorded the first answer despite setting the @bind-Value to separate indexes of the List.

Is it at all possible to utilize dynamic data structures in Blazor Form Modeling or should I look at doing something different?

Edit: For the sake of clarity, let me dump my code here. I'm using the Radzen form libraries, which can be found [here](https://razor.radzen.com/templateform). All relevant data structures and initializers can be found below, as well.

My question lies in where I bind the RadioButtonList to the answer model: `@bind-Value=@selectedAnswers.testAnswers[curr.Key]`. Can I do this? I'm currently getting an 'index out of bounds' error in that statement.

Some code:

```html
<RadzenTemplateForm TItem="Answers" Data=@selectedAnswers Submit=@GradeExam>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> curr in shuffledAnswers){
        <RadzenCard>
            <label class="col 2 font-weight-bold"><strong>@curr.Key) @allQuestions[curr.Key.ToString()].question</strong></label>
            <RadzenRadioButtonList
                @bind-Value=@selectedAnswers.testAnswers[curr.Key]
                TValue="int" Name=@(curr.Key.ToString())
                Orientation="Radzen.Orientation.Vertical"
            >
                <Items>
                    @foreach (string s in curr.Value){
                        <RadzenRadioButtonListItem Text=@s Value=@curr.Value.IndexOf(s) />
                        Console.WriteLine("radio button");
                    }
                </Items>
            </RadzenRadioButtonList>
            <RadzenRequiredValidator Component=@(curr.Key.ToString()) Text="This question is required." Popup="true" />
            @if(submitted){
                <br/><label class="col 2 font-weight-bold"><em>@allQuestions[curr.Key.ToString()].tooltip</em></label>
            }
        </RadzenCard>
    }

    <RadzenCard>
        @if(!submitted){
            <RadzenButton ButtonType="Radzen.ButtonType.Submit" Text="Submit" style="background-color: royalblue;" />
        }
        else {
            <!-- go back to course list -->
        }
    </RadzenCard>
</RadzenTemplateForm>
```

```cs
@code{

  // test answer binding model
  private class Answers{
    List<string> Answers;
    public TestAnswers(){
      Answers = new List<string>();
    }
  }

  private Answers selectedAnswers;
  private Dictionary<int, List<string>> shuffledAnswers;
  private Dictionary<string, Question> allQuestions;
  // ^ Question class contains the question and associated answers

  private void ShuffleAnswers{
    
    // iterate through all question data
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Question> q in allQuestions){

      // generate temporary string to hold answers
      List<string> temp = new List<string>();
      temp.Add(q.Value.correct);
      temp.Add(q.Value.wrong1);

      // if multiple choice w/ 4 answers, add them too
      if(q.Value.wrong2 != "N/A"){
        temp.Add(q.Value.wrong2);
        temp.Add(q.Value.wrong3);
      }

      List<string> ans = new List<string>();
      shuffledAnswers.Add(int.Parse(q.Key), ans);

      // move a random answer from temp to the list of shuffled answers
      while(temp.Count > 0){
        int index = new Random(DateTime.Now.GetHashCode()).Next(temp.Count);
        shuffledAnswers[int.Parse(q.Key)].Add(temp[index]);
        temp.RemoveAt(index);
      }

      // initialize selected answer indexes
      selectedAnswers.testAnswers.Add(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're already using dynamic code. In fact, all the examples are dynamic. The problem here is the code itself - it's adding one column after the other instead of adding rows. On top of that, instead of binding to a single item, you have two separate lists of items, one for questions and one for answers. Use a single object instead that contains the question, options and selected answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean by columns and rows?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by `class="col-12 row` which is itself wrong. That's not how iteration works in C#, not just Blazor. To generate ordered/numbered lists in HTML, use `<ol>` instead of writing the numbers explicitly. You shouldn't have to use indexes at all

Comment: Use properties, not fields. Only properties are part of an object's API. Fields are just implementation details. A public field is a public implementation detail that probably already generates a compiler warning

Comment: What validation process are you using?  I ask because you have a complex object, and your comments would suggest you are trying to use the standard validation model.  It doesn't work with complex objects.  Take a look look at `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator`.

Comment: Edited for more clarity.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm not sure what you mean by a complex object. If you're talking about the actual C# class, no, I'm not. I'm not that good.

Comment: A complex object is an object that contains other objects, or collection of objects.  I see from your updated question that you are using Radzen.  As I'm unfamiliar with that framework, I'll sign off and leave someone else to answer your question.